# Liferay organization portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet, liferay-ide

Is there any way to make a portlet for organizations i have made in control panel ?

it must be like this >> users logged in and see a portlet for their organizations and can edit update delete upon there request .

**i have created organization hierarchy and made every things roles users ... etc**

*it can be done through hook or what please help me ?!*

[i have tried this](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/32537371)

Answer (score 0):

You can add portlet in control panel by adding below lines in your

```
<control-panel-entry-category>content</control-panel-entry-category>
<control-panel-entry-weight> 9.5</control-panel-entry-weight>
```

So your  liferay-portlet.xml will look like

```
    <liferay-portlet-app>

        <portlet>
            <portlet-name>Test Portlet</portlet-name>
            <icon>/icon.png</icon>
            <control-panel-entry-category>content</control-panel-entry-category>
            <control-panel-entry-weight> 9.5</control-panel-entry-weight>
             <instanceable>false</instanceable>
            <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
            <footer-portlet-javascript> /js/main.js
            </footer-portlet-javascript> 
<css-class-wrapper>
                test-portlet
            </css-class-wrapper>
            <add-default-resource>true</add-default-resource> 
        </portlet>
        <role-mapper>
            <role-name>administrator</role-name>
            <role-link>Administrator</role-link>
        </role-mapper>
        <role-mapper>
            <role-name>guest</role-name>
            <role-link>Guest</role-link>
        </role-mapper>
        <role-mapper>
            <role-name>power-user</role-name>
            <role-link>Power User</role-link>
        </role-mapper>
        <role-mapper>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
            <role-link>User</role-link>
        </role-mapper>
    </liferay-portlet-app>
```

Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: You can give permission to portlet and simply drag and drop to your public pages.

Comment: after doing this 
where i can find this in control panel ?!

Comment: i get this error Dockbar You do not have the roles required to access this portlet.

Comment: what you have done? check for the roles and permission of the portlet.

Comment: Try to login and view this portlet by omniadmin. Let me know still you got this error.

Comment: Portlet with the name TestPortlet is described in liferay-portlet.xml but does not have a matching entry in portlet.xml

Comment: <portlet-name>Test Portlet</portlet-name> should be same in liferay-portlet.xml and portlet.xml Note that TestPortlet is the name of your portlet.